# Angular 6: simple confirmation on page leaving

Tags: angular, typescript, onbeforeunload, angular-router-guards

I need to make a simple confirm window and I saw a lot of examples of how to do it with extra actions (like waiting until file uploading of form is not field). But I need just make a default confirm window with a default text (like in a pic below) to show it when the user wants to leave from the current page. And I can't completely understand what logic should I proved inside handling `before unload` event.

[image: image example]

I'm recently sorry if it a dup of some question, however, I didn't find any solution. So I have:

**example.guard.ts**

```
export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
    canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class ExampleGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {

    constructor() { }

    canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
        return component.canDeactivate() ?
            true :
            confirm('message'); // <<< does confirm window should appear from here?
    }
}
```

**example.component.ts**

```
export class ExampleComponent implements CanComponentDeactivate {

    counstructor() { }

    @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
        canDeactivate($event: any): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
            if (!this.canDeactivate($event)) {
                // what should I do here?
            }
        }
}
```

It would be wonderful if you provide a sample of code but I appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should differentiate `beforeunload` native event on `window` and canDeactivate guard.
First one is being triggered when you are trying to close tab/window. So that when it is triggered you can `confirm(...)` user and execute `event.preventDefault()` on it to cancel closing tab/window.

Talking about `CanDeactivate` guard it should return an observable/promise/plain-value of boolean which will tell you if you can deactivate current route.

So it is much better to separate two methods (one for `beforeunload` and second one for the guard). Because if you want then change behavior to not just use native confirm but your custom modal window the default event handler for `beforeunload` won't work as it handles sync code. So for `beforeunload` you can use `confirm` only to ask user not to leave the page.

```
loading = true;
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
canLeavePage($event: any): Observable<void> {
  if(this.loading && confirm('You data is loading. Are you sure you want to leave?')) {
    $event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Guard on the other hand wants boolean to be returned (or Promise, 
 or Observable). So here you can just return the result of your condition:

```
canDeactivate(): boolean {
  return this.loading && confirm('You data is loading. Are you sure you want to leave?');
}
```

So that in your `CanDeactivate` guard it will be used like `return component.canDeactivate()`

Comment: but how can I detect what option was selected (leave button or cancel button)? Because it depends on should he stay or leave

Comment: Each button should have the attribute `(click)="functionName()"` in the html, referring to which function you want to call.

Comment: canLeavePage() function giving me folloing error ->A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.ts(2355)

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is default window confirmation message. Then it is achievable by below lines of code.

```
/**
 * Browser's default confirmation dialog box.
 */
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  defaultConfirmation(): boolean {
    if (!DIRTY_FORM_CHECK) return true;
    else return false;
  }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Default confirmation dialog get appear if dirty check return **true**.
In case of no dirty situation, pop-up will not appear.

Hope this might help someone. Thanks.